# Spark Left Outer Join produces Optional.empty when it shouldn't

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, left-join, rdd

I have an RDD containing pairs of nodes and I need to assign unique ids to them.

But I'm getting an NPE and I can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm basically putting all nodes into a distinct list and then I assigns uniqueIds to them. After that I merge the original pairs with this new assignment.

The code looks like this:

```java
JavaPairRDD<Node, Node> pairs = // ... assigned previously
JavaPairRDD<Node, Long> index = pairs
        .flatMap(tuple -> Arrays.asList(tuple._1(), tuple._2()).iterator())
        .distinct()
        .zipWithUniqueId();

pairs.leftOuterJoin(index)
        .mapToPair(new MergeJoinResult())
        .mapToPair(Tuple2::swap)
        .leftOuterJoin(index)
        .mapToPair(new MergeJoinResult())
        .mapToPair(Tuple2::swap);

/*
 * Given a tuple like (node1, (node2, node1Index))
 * Creates a new tuple (node1, node2) where node1 is initialized with its index
 */
static class MergeJoinResult implements
        PairFunction<Tuple2<Node, Tuple2<Node, Optional<Long>>>, Node, Node>,
        Serializable {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Node, Node> call(Tuple2<Node, Tuple2<Node, Optional<Long>>> row) throws Exception {
        return Tuple2.apply(new Node(row._1(), row._2()._2().get()), row._2()._1());
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `row._2()._2().get()` returns Optional.empty and I get the NPE.

But this should be impossible because I'm deriving the index RDD from the pairs RDD. So a leftOuterJoin between them should always produce a match.

As a sanity check I added code to dump the entire RDD to S3 to see the contents of `pairs` and `index`. The data is there, all edges, and the proper index entry with its uniqueId. I did the dump using `toString()`.

Then I thought that the problem would be with the `equals` implementation and I performed a delombok of the code and added print statements to verify if the comparision
between objects was returning `false`. In my log, the comparison always returns `true`, so I have no idea why I'm getting the `Optional.empty` there.

Another strange thing I notice is that when I stringfy the objects in the index and perform a group by, I find duplicates in it:

```java
index
  .groupBy(t -> t._1().toString())
  .filter(t -> {
      int size = 0;
      for (Tuple2<Node, Long> value : t._2()) {
          size++;
          if (size >= 2) return true;
      }
      return false;
  });
```

The same happens if I perform a `pairs.cogroup(index)`. I get multiple entries with the same K.

I tried to perform a comparison between these objects after grouping them by their string representation but their `equals` and `hashCode` returns the same result. I'm using Lombok implementation for those.

I also tried to serialize the RDD before this code to JSON and loaded everything in my machine, but the NPE doesn't occur in my machine after I do this.

I'm a little lost here.

My next guess would be that the problem is with the serialization (I'm using Kryo). Another option that I'm going to try is to set a different partitioner for the RDD.

Any suggestions on what I could do here? I'm using Spark 3.3.1 in AWS Glue.

Edit: I changed things to serialize all Node objects into JSON strings and used that as a join key, that worked. This hints further to serialization issues, I don't think it's related to equals or hashCode because those are implemented by Lombok.

Comment: Could you please share the `Node` class details?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. PS Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS A "basically",  "essentially" or "in other words" not summarizing a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "it is false that".

Answer (score 0):

If one joins `LEFT_TABLE` to `RIGHT_TABLE` using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and there is an entity in the `LEFT_TABLE` without a corresponding match in the `RIGHT_TABLE`, you will get NULLs, yes.

In this sense, the `OUTER` specification in the JOIN is the issue. It is hard to tell from what is given, however it seems that you would prefer an `INNER JOIN` here.

See [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) for more information on the distinction

Comment: I understand that the left outer join can produce nulls. But based on the problem it shouldn't. And I don't want to use inner join because it would hide bugs like this one.